# Property Modification from int32 to int64 without lot of modification

Tags: c#, entity-framework, properties

I am stuck in a critical situation and finding no way out.

Background :
1. I have a general library that hold very basic property like record ID and IdentityKeyName etc.

1. ID are bound to database table identity key. Meaning if I load a record from database ID will have identity value.
2. This library is used in all subsequent library in main application.

Problem :

1. Currently all the tables have a identity column of type int. Everything working fine.
2. Now we have situation(911) where Identity column should be BIGINT. Problem starts here.
3. Now all my methods, function property everything fails when I try to modify ID to int64 (cast problem)

Summary :
Can we still use old property (int) with this new table (BIGINT). Is there a way I can avoid this rework.

Comment: You can get-away with using `Int32` provided you aren't at risk of integer overflow (i.e. none of your tables will have more than 2 billion rows and they're using `IDENTITY` with a seed of 1. If not, you'll run into problems eventually. Why can't you update all of your code to use `Int64` though?

Comment: What are you using (unless I missed it in your text)? EF, Linq2SQL? Not sure if it matters a lot but at least remove the assumption.

Comment: I am using EF. Sorry I missed this.